# Read the content of file with different extension in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows

I am trying to read the content of a file with different extensions. If I run this code I get a FileNotFoundException error. When I use .txt as file extension it works fine.

```
string paths = "version.info";
String Content = "";

//Read the file
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///" + paths));

using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
{
     Content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

MessageDialog msgbox1 = new MessageDialog(Content);


await msgbox1.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: Have you tried to alter the build in file properties? when you right click on the file, try to put the build action as Content as check if it works

Comment: Thanks but can you  help out how to do programmatically.

Comment: See the file version.info in your Visual Studio Solution Viewer, right-click -> properties -> verify `Build Action` is set to `Content`. This is not a programmatic thing as you are specifically including that file along with the app package (and not, say, downloading the file from the internet, in which case you would not have to do this).